# Shipping images with a C++ program

Tags: c++, image

I've done hobby development in Java for a couple of years now, and I've just started learning C++. I understand syntax fairly well, but I'm extremely confused as to many structural facets of a typical program, namely shipping images/textures with the executable. Do I extract them to a data directory? Or do I encode them into the executable? And if the latter is the case, how do I include them in the compilation process? I'm sorry to ask such a basic question, but I'm having a particularly hard time finding the answer on Google.

Comment: keyword: embedding data in executable, first 2 results are 2 SO questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288279/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005520/how-to-embed-resources-into-a-single-executable

Comment: @ratchetfreak Hm, I hadn't found those before. However, is that the best way of accomplishing this, or should the resources instead be discretely on the filesystem in some form?

Comment: @mproncace You can't ship only the exe and expect the image somehow magically be already there. Your approach is actually a good one. Of course, you could extract the file and then read it but thats not necessary since you already have the bytes in ram if you start the exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where to put the data depends on what the data is and how large it is.

You can embed the data in the executable and then just reference the byte array when you need it. This has the upside that the data is loaded in memory automatically but it will remain in memory until the game is exited. The data also cannot be changed unless you recompile the entire executable/dynamic library.

The other option is putting it in the file system under a data folder. This requires using an installer which is essentially a self-extracting compressed archive or a downloader. This also allows shipping and using DLLs and makes changing the assets easier by just changing those with an updater.

Comment: That makes sense. I would think recompilation wouldn't be as much of an issue if you're encoding the data in the executable in the first place, since it would likely be on the smaller side anyway.